# ¿Cómo puedo limitar el rango numérico en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy iniciando en Java y tengo una duda. Estoy intentando limitar el número de carácteres que se podrían añadir por pantalla pero no consigo hacerlo.
Esto es lo que estoy haciendo (código):

```
public class Mia{
   public static void main(String[] args) {       
     
     int numRegistro;
              
     // Creo números aleatorios entre 0 y 499.
         
     int numero = (int)(Math.random()*498+1);
     System.out.println("Número de registro: "+numero);
     
     // Verificar que el número de registro es correcto.

     Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Es correcto el número de Registro? (0:no / 1:si):");
     numRegistro = entrada.nextInt();
     
     if (numRegistro == 1){
         System.out.println("Sí, el número de Registro "+numero+" es correcto");
     }
     else {
        System.out.println("Anote el número de Registro correcto: ");
    }        
     numRegistro = entrada.nextInt(); } }
```

Me gustaría:

1. En la primera parte (donde está el comentario de *// Verificar que el número de registro es correcto*). Limitar los números de respuesta por pantalla, en que tan sólo se pueda escoger el 0 o el 1 (y no te permita escoger ninguno más).
2. Lo mismo para la parte del condicional (if - else). Es decir, si el número de registro no es correcto y se quiere modificar por el número correcto (que tan sólo te permita añadir números de registro entre el 0 y el 499).

Espero que se entienda a qué me refiero y puedan ayudarme.
Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Un bucle. Mientras el número introducido no te guste, vuelves a pedir un número y lo lees. El usuario se cansará antes que el ordenador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

entiendo que generas un número de registro al azar y luego quieres decirle si es correcto o no mediante 0 o 1. Para ello se puede emplear un bucle while y si no introduces uno de esos dos números indicárselo al usuario. Aquí te dejo el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
     
     int numRegistro;
              
     // Creo números aleatorios entre 0 y 499.
         
     int numero = (int)(Math.random()*498+1);
     System.out.println("Número de registro: "+numero);
     
     // Verificar que el número de registro es correcto.

     Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Es correcto el número de Registro? (0:no / 1:si):");
     numRegistro = 5;   //inicializamos a un valor que no sea 0 ni 1
     boolean salir = false;
     
     while(!salir) {
         
        numRegistro = entrada.nextInt();
         if (numRegistro == 1){
            System.out.println("Sí, el número de Registro "+numero+" es correcto");
            salir = true;
         }
         else if (numRegistro == 0){
             System.out.println("El número de registro no es correcto");
             salir = true;
         }  
         else {
              System.out.println("Anote el número de Registro correcto (0 o 1): ");
         }
         
     } 
        System.out.println("se acabó");
    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda y el código :).